# Foreach very slow C#

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a foreach, in this foreach I go through a list and within this foreach I have a condition to check if in another list that have 200 thousand row there is certain information that is a string.

I would like make it more quickly.

```
  foreach(var dto in List){
    // the problem is here
    if(anotherList.Any(d => d.id == dto.id && d.line.equals(dto.line))) 
          continue;
    }
```

I hope make it faster.

Comment: `Any` is potentially expensive. I'd maybe make up a lookup table to find `d`s by `id` so you don't need to do a linear search for `dto.id`. Lookup the `d` that matches `dto.Id`, then do the equality check on that if it's found.

Comment: It's not `foreach` that's slow. It's the brute force search in 200K items that's slow. If you repeat that 200K-item search N times you'll have N times the delay. Why don't you use a database? Or a dictionary with `id` as the key?

Comment: If you used a dictionary you could write `if (anotherDict.TryGetValue(dtoid,out var d) && d.line==dto.line){ ...}`. If you only want to see if there's a match, `List.Any(dto=>....)`

Comment: I made it because I have many strings for a id, so I need compare the string in condition too.

Comment: I've run code like this often and it runs extremely fast.  Your system must be slow.  Are you using all the memory?  What type of disk is the database on?  Is the disk fragmented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Any` has complexity of `O(n)` where n is number of elements in the collection (`anotherList`) so you code has overall complexity of `O(m*n)` where m is number of elements in `List`. If `id` is unique then you can create lookup dictionary which should have constant lookup time in general case and do something like:

```
var dict = anotherList
  .ToDictionary(d => d.Id);

foreach(var dto in List)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue(dto.Id, out var val) && val.line.equals(dto.line))
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Which should reduce complexity to `O(m+n)`.

If you have several strings per Id you can consider following options:

1. Use [`Lookup<TKey,TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=net-8.0) in case when there are not much strings per Id:

> Represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values.

`var lookup = anotherList.ToLookup(d => d.Id)` and then search collection of matched elements

2. Build dictionary from `Id` to `HashSet<strings>` and check the hashset too :

```
var dictOfSets = anotherList
    .GroupBy(d => d.Id)
    .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr.Select(d => d.Line).ToHashSet());

foreach(var dto in List)
{
    if (dictOfSets.TryGetValue(dto.Id, out var val) && val.Contains(dto.Line))
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

3. Try leveraging [value tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) with it's generated `GetHashcode` and `Equals` to build corresponding hashtable (basic idea is the same - you need "constant" lookup):

```
var hashSet = anotherList
    .Select(d => (d.Id, d.Line))
    .ToHashSet();

foreach(var dto in List)
{
    if (hashSet.Contains((dto.Id, dto.Line)))
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Read more:

- [Time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)
- [Know Thy Complexities!](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/)
- [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-8.0)

  > The `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` generic class provides a mapping from a set of keys to a set of values. Each addition to the dictionary consists of a value and its associated key. Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` class is implemented as a hash table.
- [Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/collections#keyvalue-pair-collections) doc.

Comment: The third suggestion make it faster. Thanks!